# Retain combobox value when wb closes

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

In continuation to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180858/combobox-retain-last-selected-values-vba) how do I easily store the combobox value after the workbook closes ? For example, if the last combobox value was may when I closed the workbook, next time I open it againg, I would like the combobox list value to be set to may.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

However, you can store data in a workbook in an Excel Name object, and you can also store data in a `CustomDocumentProperty` object. Say the value you want to store is a number, like 7. To store the data in a Name object:

```
Names.Add Name:="VersionNumber", RefersTo:=7
```

and to change it:

```
Names("VersionNumber").Value = 8
```

This has the advantage that the name can be referred to in a cell formula (i.e., `=VersionNumber` will yield 8 in the cell)

Similarly, to create a new `CustomDocumentProperty`:

```
ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add _
Name:="Version Number", _
LinkToContent:=False, _
Type:=msoPropertyTypeNumber, _
Value:=7
```

and to change it:

```
ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("Version Number").Value = 12
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why, but the `CustomDocumentProperty` 
 doesn't work, probably because of the system restrictions imposed by the IT admins, but I did find a workaround with the `Workbook.BeforeClose ` [Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-beforeclose-event-excel) Function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create hidden field on your form and store combo box value into field when you close workbook.

Comment: Check this it might help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/combobox-boundcolumn-property-access

Answer (score 0):

I have found and used the `Workbook.BeforeClose` Event Function to solve the problem.